# Encryption Method Used by Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise

What encryption method is used by Magento Enterprise to save sensitive data (customer passwords etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento EE uses `sha256` for encryption. You can take a look at the method `Enterprise_Pci_Model_Encryption::hash` for more details.