# What is the data encryption / hashing key management method used in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, security

Like in the title.

**What is the data encryption / hashing key management method used in Magento 2?**

I found this question [Encryption Method Used by Magento Enterprise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65695/encryption-method-used-by-magento-enterprise), however, is the same method used on Magento 2 Community Edition?

I think admin account passwords are hashed using MD5 if I'm not wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 use the Secure Hash Algorithm `SHA-256` to hash all data that does not require decryption and Advanced Encryption Standard  `AES-256` is used to encrypt all data that requires decryption.

[Source](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/encryption-key.html?highlight=SHA-256)

Comment: What about the MD5, is that not used anywhere?